# Why was Natasha Romanoff in hiding with Team Captain America?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, the people who side with Steve Rogers, including Wanda Maximoff (Scarlet Witch), Sam Wilson (Falcon), Clint Barton (Hawkeye) & Scott Lang (Ant-Man) are imprisoned by Secretary Ross for aiding Bucky Barnes's (Winter Soldier) escape. Steve Rogers then rescues them from the prison. So all the people mentioned above are wanted fugitives of the US government.

But in *Avengers: Infinity War*, we see that Natasha Romanoff has also joined them and they are currently hiding in Scotland. However, Natasha sided with Tony Stark and the government in signing the Sokovia accords. Although she does let Steve escape with Bucky in Civil War, she isn't imprisoned by the government and is not considered a fugitive.

What transpired between Civil War and Infinity War that led Natasha Romanoff to go into hiding with Team Captain America?

Comment: Black Widow has sympathies with all sides in the "civil war" and as you say she helps them escape the airport. She has a history of working with Cap.  There's nothing stopping Team Captain America trusting her to know where they are.

Comment: @iandotkelly she's doesn't just show up at Scotland. It appears she's been travelling with them. Because she says to Wanda that she should have been in regular touch with them or something in that quinjet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because she ditched the accord and Ross knows about it, as explained in *Captain America: Civil War* itself:

> **Tony Stark:** You let them go, Nat.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** We played this wrong.
>
> **Tony Stark:** 'We'? Boy, it must be hard to shake the whole double agent thing, huh? It sticks in the DNA.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Are you incapable of letting go of your ego for one goddamn second?
>
> **Tony Stark:** T'Challa told Ross what you did, so… **they're coming for you.**
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** I'm not the one that needs to watch their back. [She walks away.] - [source](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War)

Comment: I remembered now that she electrocuted T'Challa when he ran for the chopper. But I don't remember this scene. Does it take place before T'Challa learns the truth about Zemo's plan. Then it would make sense

Comment: It take place before Iron man and captain america fight